# Servicemix import all dependencies

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix

I'm creating new project for Servicemix 4.4.0. My project will consist of several modules and one parent pom.xml, here is an example:

```
+- Module1
+- Module2
+- pom.xml (parent)
```

Each module contains  element referring to the parent pom.

I was thinking about declaring all Servicemix dependencies in parent pom. This way, I would get rid of versions in child modules.

So my question is, how to include all Servicemix dependencies in my parent pom.xml without typing them directly one by one? Perhaps there is a way to import some Servicemix parent pom or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Servicemix4 is just an OSGi container with a bunch of features/bundles already installed, you don't want to import all the Servicemix dependencies into your project.  Instead, build your project (using the maven-bundle-plugin) using only the dependencies necessary for your project and then deploy it into Servicemix4.

see these pages for more information...

http://servicemix.apache.org/SMX4/creating-a-bundle-using-maven.html

http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/servicemix-developer-machine-setup.html

If you are just looking for the latest versions of artifacts, then you can get them here...

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/smx4/features/trunk/pom.xml

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I wanted to do. I just wanted to import all dependencies for a concrete version of Fuse/Servicemix to my parent pom.xml. This does not mean, that I'll use all of them in my child modules. I just want to get rid of versions in child poms.

Comment: you'll need to just copy/paste them into your pom...but I would just start building your app with whatever versions you want to use and then Servicemix will tell you what is missing when you install your bundle.  If necessary, just install any missing dependent bundles before your bundle, etc...